# Google Geocode API credentials not working on the URL

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoding-api

I have implemented Google Geocoding API and it works as expected. Then due to security measures we decided to apply Referer based restrictions.

For which I have added *.mydomain.com/*

All the pages coming from server of subdomain.com works fine.

I have a angular page running on other server with same domain. Its accessed as https://ap1.mydomain.com/page1 on this page 1 the error of reffered not whitelisted has received.

I have tried following combination for white listing

```
*.domain.com
*.domain.com/*
https://ap1.mydomain.com/page1
```

Nothing works. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The comment helped to get Indeed this helped to get around the issue. However the situaiton is that we do not get dynamic IP address for our servers. Its on a CDN which keeps changing. and also we do not want to show the API key in the javascript requests. Any suggestions or thoughts. Our application is a dockerized container. –

Answer (score 1):

### Client-side vs Server-side API key Application Restrictions

Are you by any means using the server side? Please note that there's a [client side](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) and a [server side](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/overview) for Geocoding API.

You can set a [referer based restriction](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-security-best-practices#:%7E:text=Maps%20JavaScript%20API-,HTTP%20referer%20restriction,-Geocoding%20API%2C%20Maps) when you are using the **client-side** Geocoding service in Maps Javascript API, but when you are using the **server-side** of Geocoding API, what you have to use is [**IP address restriction**](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-security-best-practices#:%7E:text=Geocoding%20API-,IP%20address%20restriction,-(4)).

To learn more, please read the best practices doc: https://developers.google.com/maps/api-security-best-practices#api-key-table-sup-4

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. Indeed this helped to get around the issue. However the situaiton is that we do not get dynamic IP address for our servers. Its on a CDN which keeps changing. and also we do not want to show the API key in the javascript requests.  Any suggestions or thoughts. Our application is a dockerized container.

Comment: The best practices doc I provided on the answer should suffice for your needs: It says there that you can secure your project by - Restricting your API keys
,Using separate API keys for each app
,Deleting unused API keys
,Be careful when regenerating keys
,Monitoring your API usage
,Do not embed API key directly in code
,Do not store API key in source tree